# Cannot get FileLeafRef property in SharePoint Rest API

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Hi we are trying to retrieve the link URL of page in Site Pages using REST API the problem is that we cannot find the Name FileLeafRef property value.FileLeafReaf = null.

[image]

[image]

```
function fn_getListItems(webUrl,listTitle, queryText) 
{
    var viewXml = '<View><Query>' + queryText + '</Query></View>';
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems"; 
    var queryPayload = {  
               'query' : {
                      '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
                      'ViewXml' : viewXml  
               }
    };
    return fn_executeJson(url,"POST",null,queryPayload);
}


function fn_getListViewItems(webUrl,listTitle,viewTitle)
{
     var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/Views/getbytitle('" + viewTitle + "')/ViewQuery";
     return fn_executeJson(url).then(
         function(data){         
             var viewQuery = data.d.ViewQuery;
             return fn_getListItems(webUrl,listTitle,viewQuery); 
         });
}

function fn_executeJson(url,method,headers,payload) 
{
    method = method || 'GET';
    headers = headers || {};
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }      
    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if (typeof payload != 'undefined') {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(payload);
    }  
    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint stores the full URL of a file in a hidden column `EncodedAbsUrl`.

So, you can request it explicitly as:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items?$select=*,EncodedAbsUrl
```

After that, you can directly use it somewhat as below, watch out for the quotes :

```
var items = data.d.results;

$.each(items, function(index, value) {  
//Append results to DIV
    $("#lstGlobalNews").append("<tr><td class='ms-vb2'><a href="+value.EncodedAbsUrl+" target='_blank'>"+value.Title+"</a></td><td class='ms-vb2' style='text-align: right;'>"+fn_FormatDate(value.Date_x0020_Posted)+"</td></tr>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve `FileLeafRef` property, it needs to be *explicitly* specified in `$select` query option, for example:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items?$select=FileLeafRef
```

As alternative option it could also be retrieved via `File` resource, for example:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items?$select=File/Name&$expand=File
```

Answer (score 1):

The FileLeafRef property only get the file name. If you want to get the file url, we need use ServerRelativeUrl property of file.

The REST API using this.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site%20Pages')/items?$select=File/ServerRelativeUrl&$expand=File
```